# Validating a has_many belongs to a user and validation returning both true and false

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Attempting to validate that an attachment belongs to a user when a product is created.

validates_presence_of :attachment_id, if: :attachment?

```
  before_save :validate_attachment_id, if: :attachment?

  private

  def attachment?
    product_type == 1
  end

  def validate_attachment_id
    @attachments = Attachment.find_by(user_id: Product.current_user.id, id: attachment_id)
    if @attachments.present?
      true
    else
      errors.add(:attachment_id, 'does not belong to you or does not exist')
      false
    end
  end
```

The outcome when a attachment that belongs to the user is fine, it saves as expected. When it's an attachment that doesn't belong, it returns both true and false?

[image: Issue with the validation]

The attachment model cannot have a `belongs_to :product`, but the product model does have a `has_many :attachments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`before_save` is called after the validation.

You should use `validate :validate_attachment_id, if: :attachment?` instead.

Comment: Yeah, by the time `before_save` kicks in the model's already slated to be saved, but this should trigger `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`.

Comment: @tadman it won't, because it's not a part of the validation process. The object will still be `valid?`. Adding `errors` before or after doesn't affect the saving.

Comment: I mean the `false` part.

Comment: It won't raise an exception unless saved with `save!` etc. 
We don't know how the flash message is created too.

Comment: @Bartosz it's raised after `if @model.save`

Comment: @Bartosz this seems to have done it, is there no built in method for validating a belongs_to via something like a user_id? Thanks.